# Error when compare big numbers

Tags: awk, test, numeric-data, file-comparison

Trying to use this

```
#!/bin/bash

SIZE=$(redis-cli info | grep used_memory: | awk -F':' '{print $2}')
MAX=19000000000

if [ "$SIZE" -gt "$MAX" ]; then
    echo 123
fi
```

But always getting: "Ganzzahliger Ausdruck erwartet"

When I echo SIZE I get a value like 2384934 - I dont have to / can convert a value or can / do I?

OUTPUT of redis-cli info:

```
# Memory
used_memory:812136
used_memory_human:793.10K
used_memory_rss:6893568
used_memory_rss_human:6.57M
used_memory_peak:329911472
used_memory_peak_human:314.63M
total_system_memory:16760336384
total_system_memory_human:15.61G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
mem_fragmentation_ratio:8.49
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0
```

EDIT: I found the mistake - I used print in the awk command - without it it works.

```
SIZE=$(redis-cli info | grep used_memory: | awk -F':' '{$2}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers you use seems to be very big for `bash`. You can try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
SIZE=$(redis-cli info |  awk -F':' '$1=="used_memory" {print int($2/1000)}')
MAX=19000000
if [ "$SIZE" -gt "$MAX" ]; then
    echo 123
fi
```

Comment: This did not fix it - the value now is -> 0.812136

Comment: @Isengo, see my corrected answer

Comment: Now the output is really weird - check_size.sh: Zeile 5: [: 812
0
6893
0
329911
0
37
0: Ganzzahliger Ausdruck erwartet.

Comment: @Isengo, I do not understand German, so please translate the error in English. And please post in your question the result of `redis-cli info` command.

Comment: found the error. I removed the print and it works.

Comment: SIZE=$(redis-cli info | grep used_memory: | awk -F':' '{$2}')

Comment: I find the error in my script :) Update it to return only one result

Comment: Jup works - and now I am saving the grep - thanks :)

Comment: @Isengo you rarely need `grep` and `awk` together. In this case you can use `SIZE=$(redis-cli info | awk -F':' '$1=="used_memory" {$2}')`